# Complex HTML issue with huge data set to show in one page

Tags: html, css, ajax, optimization, html-table

Person -> Item - > Work -> Component.
This are the main tables in the database.
I have to search for Item by a criteria. It will give a list. I will join the Person to get his "parent". After this maybe is a record in Work table maybe not, but if is, I will join also for Work I will join the list of Components if can be found.

The original code it was with nested tables. It will crash the browser, because taking to much memory with that design and is extremely slow around 150 records.

I rewrote it with divs the nested table. The performance got a huge boost, but start to be slow again because of buttons and design. ( It wasn't able to show 200 record before even after 10 min waiting!, now display 5k rows in 23 seconds)

Some of my benchmark logs:

```
SQL execution time: 0.18448090553284 seconds. Found 5624 rows.
For each result processing took: 0.29220700263977 seconds. 
Writing the HTML code took:0.4107129573822 seconds.
Rows in HTML: 26551 headers + data.
Total Cells in HTML: **302491**  headers and data.

Time until DOMready: 23691 milliseconds (in JavaScript)
```

0.18 + 0.29 + 0.41 = 0.88 So is around 1 second!
But when the browser actually want to show it to you ( paint ) it will take like 20 seconds!!!

1. Please don't suggest the paging! - the customer (final user) want to see all data in 1 web page for whatever his reason. No comment here.
2. Running on an i7 processor and 8/16 GB ram as requirement is accepted.

Most of the data rows has a collapse/expand button.
Most of the data row has the CRUD buttons: Add, Edit, Delete, View in details
All 4  kind of data table has headers and they don't match the length of the other kind of table header size, neither in column numbers.

When I want to just list the data in a blank page ( without design) and use 1 single table it is like 2 seconds or 3, not 20-30.

The original nested table solution has buttons with functionality in data row.
I would like to use it, and not implement it again.

My idea is to go back to the original nested table design ( to not re implement a lot of functionality of buttons) Then display only the top level table collapsed, with expand buttons. Then call an AJAX to get the second level data, when ready call the 3rd level then the 4th level.
The user is using intranet or the same PC as the server, so this maybe can be acceptable? -and doesn't have a blocking user interface for long time.

How would you handle this case, when there is not an option to show a next page button with 20 records / page.

Comment: yes, ajax seems to be a right choice